# Capitalize journal title for apa in Latex

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, apa-style

I am using overleaf to put together my references that follow the apa 7th edition. The journal titles however are not capitalized. How do I correct that? Note that I tried the method suggested in this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72032922/capitalize-journal-name-in-latex but it didn't work for me.

Here is a minimal reproducible example:

```
\documentclass[man]{apa7}

\usepackage[american]{babel}

\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=apa,uniquename=false,sortcites=true,sorting=nyt,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{american-apa}
\addbibresource{refs.bib}

\begin{document}
\parencite{golinkoff1979comparison} said this 
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

My `refs.bib` here

```
@article{golinkoff1979comparison,
  title={A comparison of fathers' and mothers' speech with their young children},
  author={Golinkoff, Roberta Michnick and Ames, Gail Johnson},
  journal={Child development},
  pages={28--32},
  year={1979},
  publisher={JSTOR}
}
```

The reference prints this:
[image]

Following @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz code, I encountered another problem: the journal title is missing
[image]

Comment: It is a huge waste of users time if you cross post on multiple sites without adding links to all other versions to all your questions!

Comment: x-post https://stackoverflow.com/q/74970530/2777074

Comment: Sorry @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz first time posting a Tex question and so don't know where the best location is.

Comment: The location does not matter, what matters is that you mention all other versions in every version of your question. Otherwise you risk users wasting their time in trying to answer a question which already has an answer or future users not finding a solution which might have been posted to one of the other versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same method as in the post you linked to:

```
\documentclass[man]{apa7}

\usepackage[american]{babel}

\title{text}
\shorttitle{short title}

\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=apa,uniquename=false,sortcites=true,sorting=nyt,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{american-apa}

\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{\jobname.bib}
@article{golinkoff1979comparison,
  title={A comparison of fathers' and mothers' speech with their young children},
  author={Golinkoff, Roberta Michnick and Ames, Gail Johnson},
  journal={Child development},
  pages={28--32},
  year={1979},
  publisher={JSTOR}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage{mfirstuc}
\DeclareFieldFormat{journaltitle}{\capitalisewords{#1}}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\parencite{golinkoff1979comparison} said this 
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I can't replicate your result. The journal title is missing. See my edits.

Comment: @cliu Did you use the exact same code as in my answer with all the added packages?

Comment: yes, I copied and pasted the whole thing

Comment: Please show your .log file

Comment: The raw log is very long but there was an warning "Package biblatex Warning: The starred command '\DeclareDelimAlias*' is deprecated. Use the unstarred version '\DeclareDelimAlias' instead."

Comment: You could try to add it to your question. Or use a service like pastebin.com

Comment: Here is the link on pastebin.com https://pastebin.com/0FAEUZT9. I really appreciate your time

Comment: I suggest to first try to recompile from scratch, e.g. delete all the auxiliary files and then rerun latex and biber. If this does not help, you could try updating your texlive installation. Your apa style and several other packages are not the currently distributed versions.

Comment: After a few more attempts, I was able to reproduce your results. I accepted your answer. However, can you italicize the journal title `Child Development`?